# Show issues with no tasks with Jira without losing priority

Tags: jira, agile, jira-agile

In Jira Agile. In the Work view. When an issue has no tasks it looses its prioriy and goes down the page in the "other issues" section.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution of the problem?

Comment: Nope. It's the way jira works. Anyway, we are not using tasks anymore. We keep stories small.

Comment: Thank you... we need subtasks for most issues, so maybe we will have to create subtask even when we don't need it. :/

Comment: Have you found a ticket or a feature request on Atlassian?

Answer (score 0):

In the board's configuration, go to **Swimlanes > Base Swimlanes on: Query**.

For the JQL of the query, enter:
**ORDER BY Priority**

This will order issues only by Priority, so that High priority issues with no subtasks will be above low priority issues with many subtasks.

Comment: This is a great idea, but I already tried it and it doesn't suit our requirements. We need to keep a single issue (with subtasks) in a single row (swimlane). And when grouping by query it only shows a single swimlane with all the issues in it, loosing clear visibility on what is happening!

Comment: Update your board's Saved Filter to exclude sub-tasks by adding this to the JQL: "AND type != Sub-task". This will stop the sub-tasks from being displayed.